# Pandas : Add new unnamed columns to existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have an existing dataframe and an np array like so:

```
[[ 0.3397825   0.6602175 ]
 [ 0.3397825   0.6602175 ]
 ...,
 [ 0.89700502  0.10299498]]
```

The number of rows in this array matches my dataframe row count. I just want to add two new columns to my dataframe with column headers like "prob0, prob1".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html)

```
pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(ary,columns=['prob0', 'prob1'])],axis=1)
```

Data Input

```
ary=[[ 0.3397825 , 0.6602175 ],
 [ 0.3397825 ,  0.6602175 ],
 [ 0.89700502  ,0.10299498]]
```

Comment: Indeed! Works perfect. Thank you.

Comment: @shikhanshu yw：-）